# react native, dynamic background image does not work

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, jsx

I am making an app in which I am adding the darkMode, my app has an "imagebackground" which should change depending on the theme of the phone.

I have been trying various ways which have not worked for me so far. I am new to react native and I would like you to help me find a solution.

Here is what I currently have:

```
function HomeScreen(props){ 
      const scheme=useColorScheme();
      let imagen = "img/background.jpg";
      if(scheme === 'dark'){
        imagen = "img/blackfullblack.jpg";
    
      return (
        <ImageBackground fadeDuration={0} resizeMode = "stretch" style ={styles.container} 
          source = { require ("./" + imagen)} 
        > }
       ...etc...
```

first of all, Thanks :)

Comment: Hard to tell without the `ImageBackground` code

Comment: Maybe you could share the style you set to the `ImageBackground`? usually that happens if `width` and `height` are not set

Comment: Welcome to SO! "...various ways which have not worked for me so far." -- can you elaborate on this a bit more specifically, please? What exactly isn't working in these attempts? Please provide a [mcve] and clear problem description. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`metro` doesn't support dynamic imports, so you need to change your code to utilise static imports instead like this:

```js
let imagen = require("./img/background.jpg");
if (scheme === 'dark'){
  imagen = require("./img/blackfullblack.jpg");
}

return <ImageBackground fadeDuration={0} resizeMode="stretch" style={styles.container} source={imagen} />
```